# Get response from a soap service using xpath (error: prefix must resolve to a namespace: soap )

Tags: java, xpath, soap, apache-camel

I am consuming a soap service using apache camel. I am receiving the following response:

```
INFO 17:49:59.662 - 
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
           <ns2:consultaCEPResponse xmlns:ns2="http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/">
                <return>
                     <bairro>zzzzzz</bairro>
                     <cep>000000</cep>
                     <cidade>tttttt</cidade>
                     <complemento2>yyyyy</complemento2>
                     <end>xxxxxxxx</end>
                     <uf>wwwww</uf>
                 </return>
          </ns2:consultaCEPResponse>
     </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get only the content contained within the return tag. However I get the following error:

**prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns2**

**But when I change the prefix to ns2, it asks for the prefix to be soap.**

What should I do to get what's inside the return tag?

This is my code:

```
public class RotaEnviaPedidos {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("file:pedidos?noop=true")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,simple("POST"))
            .to("https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente")
            .transform().xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:consultaCEPResponse/return/text()",  
                    new Namespaces("soap","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"))
            .log("${body}");
        }
    });

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    context.stop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add the missing namespace declaration in your XPath expression. Something like :

```
transform().xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:consultaCEPResponse/return//text()",  
                    new Namespaces("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
        .add("ns2", "http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/"))
```

If this doesn't work, one way to do it could also be :

```
transform().xpath("//*[local-name()='return']//text()")
```

Note : I've added one `/` to your XPath expression (`//text()`) since no text is directly descendant from the return element.

Comment: It worked, but now it prints everything on the same line:
Jardim das Acácias04707900São PauloAvenida Roque Petroni Júnior 1089SP
instead of: 
<bairro>Jardim das Acácias</bairro><cep>04707900</cep><cidade>São Paulo</cidade><complemento2></complemento2><end>Avenida Roque Petroni Júnior 1089</end><uf>SP</uf>

Comment: What happen if you replace in the XPath expression `//text()`  with `/*` ?